# Forcing html element to not be wider than the page

Tags: html, css

Imagine you have a complex structure with 2  elements in a table cell. Just like that:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="wideDiv">Here goes some very wide content</div>
                <div class="anotherDiv">This content doesn't have to be wide.</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

.wideDiv has content that may be wider than the page itself. In this case it forces .anotherDiv to get all this space too. I'd want to force .wideDiv to be not wider than the page itself (using scroll, of course), it works this way if we don't wrap divs with table. Fixed size is an obvious solution, but is there any other way?

Here's working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GbEvT/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
.anotherDiv {
width: 100vw;
}
```

Here's the update: http://jsfiddle.net/GbEvT/4/

It tells anotherDiv to take 100% of the screen, not more.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have another solution:

```
table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```